# "Соперница за титул" - так можно?

Tags: управление

> Она <Элеонора Дузе> была многолетней соперницей Сары Бернар за титул
>   лучшей театральной актрисы мира.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Она <Элеонора Дузе> была многолетней соперницей Сары Бернар **в борьбе за** титул лучшей театральной актрисы мира.

СОПЕРНИК, Эти команды - соперники в борьбе за мировое первенство. У неё нет **соперниц в чём-л.** (нет равных).

Comment: То же самое хотел сказать: *в борьбе за титул*.

Comment: Что-то в этом роде нужно добавить для грамматики, но по стилю хочется смягчить добавляемое: выходит, что они "боролись", хотя титул условный, и "борьба" или (помягче) "состязание" могли существовать только в мыслях театральных критиков. На самом же деле актрисы могли стремиться только к большему, чем у соперницы, успеху у публики.